# Django 1.9 won't render the right page in links

Tags: python, django

demo/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include, patterns
from django.contrib import admin

import views
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('demo.urls',
    url(r'^admin', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', views.login, name="login"),
    url(r'^resetpwd', views.resetpwd, name='resetpwd'),
    url(r'^mechanics/', include('mechanics.urls', namespace="mechanics")),
)
```

mechanics/urls.py

```
import views

from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('mechanics.urls',
    url(r'^admin', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', views.login, name="login"),
    url(r'^resetpwd', views.resetpwd, name='resetpwd'),
    url(r'^loandelinquency', views.loandelinquency, name='loandelinquency'),
)
```

mechanics/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
import cPickle

def loandelinquency(request):
    return render(request, 'mechanics/LoanDelinquency.html')

def login(request):
    try:
        users = cPickle.load(open('users.p', 'rb'))
    except:
        users = {'user@email.com':'**********'}
        cPickle.dump(users, open('users.p', 'wb'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            users = cPickle.load(open('users.p', 'rb'))
        except:
            users = {'user@email.com':'**********'}
            cPickle.dump(users, open('users.p', 'wb'))
        user = request.POST.get('user','')
        pwd = request.POST.get('pwd', '')
        request.session['user'] = user
        request.session['pwd'] = pwd
        try:
            if user in users:
                if users[user] == pwd:
                    return render(request, 'mechanics/inside.html')
                else:
                    wronguser = ''
                    wrongpwd = 'Wrong password.'
                    return render(request, 'mechanics/login.html', {'wrongpwd': wrongpwd, 'wronguser':wronguser})
            else:
                wronguser = 'Wrong username'
                wrongpwd = ''
                return render(request, 'mechanics/login.html', {'wrongpwd': wrongpwd, 'wronguser':wronguser})
        except:
            return render(request, 'mechanics/login.html')
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'mechanics/login.html')

def resetpwd(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, "resetpwd.html")
```

mechanics/templates/mechanics/login.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <title>Data Science Demo</title>
            <h1 align="center">Ninja's</h1>
                <br>
                <div align="center"><font size=24>Login</font>
                <br>
                    <form align="center" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        E-mail<br>
                        <input type="text" align="center" name="user"><br>
                        Password<br>
                        <input type="password" align="center" name="pwd"><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                    {% if wrongpwd %}
                        <br>
                        <font color="red">{{ wrongpwd }}</font><br>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if wronguser %}
                        <br>
                        <font color="red">{{ wronguser }}</font>
                    {% endif %}
                    </form>
                    <a href="{% url 'mechanics:resetpwd' %}">Reset Password</a>
                </div>
    </body>
</html>
<style>

div {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 25px;
    border: 25px solid navy;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #b0e0e6;
}
</style>
```

mechanics/templates/mechanics/resetpwd.html

```
<html>
    <title>Reset Password</title>
        <body>
            <p>You did it!</p>
        </body>
</html>
```

The `<a href="{% url 'mechanics:resetpwd' %}">Reset Password</a>` is just returning me to the login page. It does the same with every other link that I've put into to code. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include a dollar sign at the end of your regex.

```
url(r'^$', views.login, name="login"),
```

Without the dollar sign, the regex `r'^'` will match all urls, so any url patterns below this one will be ignored.

You can actually remove this url and `resetpwd` from the root url config, because you already include these views in the included `mechanics.urls`.

Note that Django comes with [an authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/). You should use this rather than trying to write your own.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code:

First and foremost, you are completely working around Django's authentication system. If you know what you are doing this is fine (though it really makes you wonder why you are using Django, then).

In any other case, you should really be using it because:

1. you are using plain text passwords (Django would not)
2. you are not authenticating the user in Django thus you will not be able to use *any* of the features that come along with Django based on authentication, like the decorator `login_required()` which will handle correct redirecting to the login page, localization, permissions, password resetting via e-mail and many more.

As a side note:

You have two `login` and `resetpw` pages, and you include the admin site twice (in the base urls.py and in the mechanics one).